# I'm trying to make a header for my table in Python but the numbers that identify each column won't align with the columns in my table

Tags: python

This program is really simple. In my program, I'm making a power table based on the number of rows by the number of columns a user puts in. For instance, if a user puts in 5 for the amount of rows, and 6 for the amount of columns, a table would appear with headers telling you how many rows there are and how many columns there are, like this:

[image: Power Table for Python]

With the code I have now, the power table works but the header for the columns at the top are not aligned, even though I made them the same spacing. Plus, I also need the underscores under the column headers as shown above. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    inputRows= 0
    inputColumns= 0 

    while (inputRows < 2) or (inputRows > 12):
        inputRows= int(input("Enter an integer value for rows between 2 and 12: "))


    while (inputColumns < 2) or (inputColumns > 12):
        inputColumns= int(input("Enter an integer value for columns between 2 and 12: "))
    powerTable= buildTable(inputColumns, inputRows, inputColumns)



    for i in range(inputRows):
        print(i, end="|")
        for j in range(inputColumns):
            powerTable[i][j]= i**j
            print("%8d" % powerTable[i][j], end= "|")
        print()


def buildTable(inputColumns, rows, cols) :
    table = []                  # initialize the tabl
    for i in range(rows) :      # for each row
        row = [0] * cols         # create a row with cols values
        table.append(row)        # and append it to the end of the table
    for i in range(inputColumns):
        print("%8d" % i, end="|")
    print()
    return table 
main()
```

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: What does your output look like at the moment?

Comment: I think its better to use `pandas` dataframe, if you want to make a table. Include a input example, please

Answer (score 0):

To create a table of dimension rows x cols, with values set to zero, you can do:

```
def build_table(rows, cols):
    """ Create a table of rows x cols values set to 0. """
    return [[0] * cols for _ in range(rows)]
```

For instance:

```
>>> build_table(3, 5)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now, if you want to create the *multiplication* table, you can do as follow:

```
def build_mul_table(rows, cols):
    """ Calculate the *mul* table. """
    return [[i * j for j in range(1, cols + 1)] for i in range(1, rows + 1)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
table = []
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    row = []
    for j in range(1, cols + 1):
        row.append(i * j)
    table.append(row)
```

For instance:

```
>>> build_mul_table(3, 5)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
```

Then, you can write a separate function to display any kind of table:

```
def print_table(table):
    cols = len(table[0])
    header = ["    "] + ["{0:4d}".format(j) for j in range(1, cols + 1)]
    print(" | ".join(header))
    header = ["----"] + ["----" for j in range(1, cols + 1)]
    print(" + ".join(header))
    for i, row in enumerate(table, 1):
        line = ["{0:4d}".format(i)]  + ["{0:4d}".format(v) for v in row]
        print(" | ".join(line))
```

The result:

```
print_table(build_mul_table(3, 5))

     |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5
---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ---- + ----
   1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5
   2 |    2 |    4 |    6 |    8 |   10
   3 |    3 |    6 |    9 |   12 |   15
```

Comment: Yes, my table works, it's just aligning the header columns and putting underscores below them.